# NullPointerException when I try to output get method

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I have an ArrayList of Question Class objects and I need to output the random selected question. everithing seems OK but when I run it, gives me a java lang nullpointerException

```
public class GameBean implements Serializable {

private Random random;
private String question; 
private String answer;
//above are the attributes
```

METHOD

```
public Question getQuestion() {
int index = random.nextInt(questionList.size());
Question q = questionList.get(index);

return q;}
```

Comment: Are you sure you initialized `random`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to

```
public Question getQuestion() {
random=new random();// this line added
int index = random.nextInt(questionList.size());
Question q = questionList.get(index);

return q;}
```

when you did `private Random random;` you have just declared that `random` is of `Random` type but you have not initialized it. As you know all non primitive instance variables are initialized with `null` as default value, so this mean you are doing operations on `null` which results `nullpointerexception`